# WPF DataTemplate do not call get

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have to 2 different ways to set a value. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r93wx.png)

1. Without DataTemplate (Parameter type) the set Method is called. Same type of all elements in this column.
2. With DataTemplate (Value) the set method is not called. I must use different templates because the values in this column are from different types.

The mainwindow.xaml Code

```
<Window x:Class="WpfGridTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:data="clr-namespace:WpfGridTest.MVVM"
    xmlns:system="clr-namespace:WpfGridTest.Common"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="300" Width="450"
    FontSize="12">

<Window.DataContext>
    <data:ParameterListViewModel/>    
</Window.DataContext>

<Grid DataContext="{Binding ParameterList}">
    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ToolBar Grid.Row="0" Background="LightGray">
        </ToolBar>

        <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" x:Name="dataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False">

            <DataGrid.Resources>
                <DataTemplate x:Key="StringTemplate">
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Value, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="2" 
                             Background="GreenYellow" Foreground="Black" />
                </DataTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:Key="EnumTemplate">
                    <ComboBox Margin="2" ItemsSource="{Binding EnumList, Mode=TwoWay}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValue="{Binding Value}" SelectedValuePath="Value" 
                              Background="GreenYellow" Foreground="Black" />
                </DataTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:Key="NumberTemplate">
                    <TextBox Margin="2" Text="{Binding Value, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                             Background="GreenYellow" Foreground="Black" TextAlignment="Right" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGrid.Resources>

            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Name" Header="Parameter name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>

                <DataGridComboBoxColumn x:Name="Type" Header="Parameter type" SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Type}"
                                        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static data:ParameterListViewModel.GetListOfParameterTypes}}"/>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Value">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplateSelector>
                        <system:ParameterTypeTemplateSelector 
                            EnumTemplate="{StaticResource EnumTemplate}" 
                            StringTemplate="{StaticResource StringTemplate}"
                            NumberTemplate="{StaticResource NumberTemplate}"/>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplateSelector>

                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

The ParameterModel.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using WpfGridTest.Common;

namespace WpfGridTest.MVVM
{
    public enum ParameterType
    {
        UINT16,
        ENUM16,
        BIT_ENUM16,
        FLOAT,
        DATE,
        STRING
    }

    public class EnumItem
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Value { get; set; }
    }

    public class Parameter : ViewModelBase
    {
        public Parameter()
        {
        }

        public Parameter(string name, ParameterType type)
        {
            Name = name;
            Type = type;
        }

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public ParameterType Type { get; set; }
        public List<EnumItem> EnumList { get; set; }
        public object Value { get; set; }

        public override void OnLoaded()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override void OnUnloaded()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
 }
```

The ParameterViewModel.cs

```
   using System.Collections.Generic;
    using WpfGridTest.Common;

    namespace WpfGridTest.MVVM
    {
        public class ParameterViewModel : ViewModelBase
        {
            #region Properties
            private string name;
            public string Name
            {
                get { return name; }
                set
                {
                    name = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged (nameof (Name));
                }
            }

            private ParameterType type;
            public ParameterType Type
            {
                get { return type; }
                set { type = value; OnPropertyChanged (nameof (Type)); }
            }

            private List<EnumItem> enumlist; 
            public List<EnumItem> EnumList
            {
                get { return enumlist; }
                set { enumlist = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(EnumList)); 
 }           }

            private object _value;
            public object Value
            {
                get { return _value; }
                set { _value = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Value)); }
            }
        }
    }
```

ParameterListViewModel.cs

public class ParameterListViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    #region Constructors

```
public ParameterListViewModel()
{
    List<EnumItem> list1 = new List<EnumItem>
    {
        new EnumItem {Name = "Item 1.1", Value = 1},
        new EnumItem {Name = "Item 1.2", Value = 2},
    };

    ParameterList = new ObservableCollection<ParameterViewModel>();
    ParameterList.Add (new ParameterViewModel { Name = "Enum 1", Type = ParameterType.ENUM16, Value=1, EnumList = list1 }) ;
    ParameterList.Add (new ParameterViewModel { Name = "String", Type = ParameterType.STRING, Value="Test String" });
    ParameterList.Add (new ParameterViewModel { Name = "Uint",   Type = ParameterType.UINT16, Value=123 });
}

private ObservableCollection<ParameterViewModel> parameterlist; 
public ObservableCollection<ParameterViewModel> ParameterList
{
    get { return parameterlist;  }
    set
    {
        parameterlist = value;
        OnPropertyChanged (nameof(ParameterList));
    }
}

public static IEnumerable<ParameterType> GetListOfParameterTypes => Enum.GetValues(typeof(ParameterType)).Cast<ParameterType>();
}
```

And at least the TemplateSelector Class

```
namespace WpfGridTest.Common
{
    public class ParameterTypeTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
    {
        public DataTemplate EnumTemplate       { get; set; }
        public DataTemplate NumberTemplate     { get; set; }
            public DataTemplate StringTemplate { get; set; }

        public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
        {
            //Parameter parameter = item as Parameter;
            ParameterViewModel parameter = item as ParameterViewModel;

            if (parameter != null)
            {
                if ((parameter.Type == ParameterType.ENUM16) || (parameter.Type == ParameterType.BIT_ENUM16))
                    return EnumTemplate;
                else if ((parameter.Type == ParameterType.STRING))
                    return StringTemplate;
                else
                    return NumberTemplate;
            }
            else
                return base.SelectTemplate(item, container);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: nice code dump where is the question?

Comment: You're right.
If I change the value, the set property of "Value" in ParameterViewModel.cs is not called. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Edit the question , people don't look in comments for corrections

Answer (score 0):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridtemplatecolumn.celltemplateselector(v=vs.110).aspx

> Gets or sets the object that determines which template to use to display the contents of a cell that is **not in editing mode**.

Comment: I don't understand. I have an CellTemplateSelector. See 
public class ParameterTypeTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector

Comment: Thats exactly it. the CellTemplate is for readonly. When the cell get focus it changes the Template to a CellEditingTemplate. Look here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridtemplatecolumn(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_7

Comment: Thanks, now it works. 

    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Value 2"
          CellEditingTemplateSelector="{StaticResource ParameterTypeSelector}"/>

But how can I use CellTemplateSelector and CellEditingTemplateSelector for the same DataGridTemplateColumn? If I only used the CellEditingTemplateSelector, no value will be shown. And If I use both, the Setter isn't called.

    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Value 2" 
        CellEditingTemplateSelector="{StaticResource ParameterTypeSelector}"
        CellTemplateSelector="{StaticResource ParameterTypeSelector}/>

What is wrong?